# Using BigQuery plugin in Grafana

Tags: docker, google-bigquery, grafana

I have some issues with the format of the provisioning file. I have some service account file that looks like this

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "my-project",
  "private_key_id": "XXXXX_my_private_key_id_XXXXXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXX_my_private_key___\nXXXXX_another_line_here_XXXXX\nXXXXXX_final_line_XXXXXX==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "my-project@company.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "123456",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/my-project%40company.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

And the provisioning file that I put in `/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/all.yaml` 
Which looks like this

```
apiVersion: 1

# list of datasources to insert/update depending
# what's available in the database
datasources:
  # <string, required> name of the datasource. Required
- name: bigquery-project
  type: doitintl-bigquery-datasource
  access: proxy
  isDefault: true
  jsonData:
  authenticationType: jwt
  clientEmail: my-project@company.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  defaultProject: my-default-project
  tokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
  secureJsonData:
  privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXX_my_private_key___\nXXXXX_another_line_here_XXXXX\nXXXXXX_final_line_XXXXXX==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  version: 2
  readOnly: false
```

But when I clicked on save and test I got some errors. I think I miss-formated the provisioning file.
I tried to upload the service account file using the UI and the test passed, I was able to query BQ. However when I did this, I couldn't find any file in `/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources` to get and example of it.

I'm executing a custom Grafana image in a docker container

```
### file system hierarchy of the project
.
├── Dockerfile
└── provisioning
    ├── dashborads
    └── datasources
        └── all.yaml
```

```
### Docker file 
ARG GRAFANA_VERSION=6.5.3
FROM grafana/grafana:$GRAFANA_VERSION
ENV GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM "true"
ENV GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED "true"
ENV GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE "Admin"
ENV GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS "doitintl-bigquery-datasource 1.0.4"
```

The way I'm running the container

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v $(pwd)/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning massy/custom-grafana
```

I'm providing the provisioning file via a volume.

What's wrong with the provisioning file ?
When we add a datasource in Grafana, isn't the provisioning file updated automatically ? (if not created then it will be ?)
How could I get the logs when I test that bigquery plugin ?

**Edit**

When I tried to add a dummy SQL query in "new dashbord" section this is what I get

```
 lvl=eror msg="Failed to get access token" logger=data-proxy-log error="private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:28 length:110 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} pkcs1PrivateKey @2"
t=2020-01-22T10:02:18+0000 lvl=info msg=Requesting logger=data-proxy-log url=https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/undefined/queries
t=2020-01-22T10:02:18+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=1 uname= method=POST path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/bigquery/v2/projects/undefined/queries status=401 remote_addr=172.17.0.1 time_ms=55 size=304 referer="http://localhost:3000/dashboard/new?panelId=2&edit&fullscreen&orgId=1&gettingstarted"
```

I did a `docker logs` on the container

Comment: Could you share the error stack trace so that we can have a better understanding on the issue you are facing?

Comment: where can I find such logs ? The plugin is in the client side

Comment: @Joaquim I added some logs

Comment: Have you checked this post? 

https://community.grafana.com/t/stackdriver-datasource-provisioning-in-5-3-0-beta3/11090

Comment: Thanks for the link @Joaquim there is a difference between the two files in https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/doitintl-bigquery-datasource?version=1.0.4 and the documentation in github https://github.com/doitintl/bigquery-grafana#example-of-provisioning-a-file

Comment: Could you add this information about the desynchronization between documentation in the answer you posted below so that the community may benefit from it?

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct format for the provisioning file

```
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
- name: bigquery-project
  type: doitintl-bigquery-datasource
  access: proxy
  isDefault: true
  jsonData:
     authenticationType: jwt
     clientEmail: my-project@company.iam.gserviceaccount.com
     defaultProject: my-default-project
     tokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
  secureJsonData:
     privateKey: |
        -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
        XXXXXXX_my_private_key___
        XXXXX_another_line_here_XXXXX
        XXXXXX_final_line_XXXXXX
        -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
  version: 2
  readOnly: false
```

There is a difference between the two provisioning files:

- https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/doitintl-bigquery-datasource?version=1.0.4
- https://github.com/doitintl/bigquery-grafana#example-of-provisioning-a-file

The one on GitHub has the correct format

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)